# Given a set indexes, aggregate between each index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given an array of indexes,

```
array([0, 12, 42, 50, 64, 67, 85, 90, 100]
```

Is there a way to get a sum of values from a dataframe `df` specifically between these indexes without looping over `df.iloc[i:i+1].sum()`?

Comment: Please provide and indexes, dataframe, and expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use this method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,100))
a = np.array([0, 12, 42, 50, 64, 67, 85, 90, 100])

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, a)).sum()
```

Output:

```
              0
(0, 12]      78
(12, 42]    825
(42, 50]    372
(50, 64]    805
(64, 67]    198
(67, 85]   1377
(85, 90]    440
(90, 100]   855
```